# Use react-table within a high order component, invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I'm currently writing a custom table component for an app. I don't feel like writing this component as a stateless component since I know for a fact that it needs to have a very robust state.

Obviously, I cannot use the react-table hooks since this is a high order component. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

class Grid extends Component {
    render() {
        const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({
            columns,
            data,
        });

        return (
           <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default Grid
```

The error message here is:

- **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

I didn't include any code on the render since that isn't the main issue, the issue is that I need to translate the hooks way to a regular HOC scenario.
I haven't been able to find a workaround for this, any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: I don't get how come this lib get popular, I also got the invalid hook from their sample code.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confusing `stateless` and `functional`. 
Hooks can only be used in functional components, but they can have state. 
Functional components can use the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hooks to implement state.

For your use case you can do something like:

```
function Grid() {
    const [gridState, setGridState] = useState()
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    });

    return (
       <div></div>
    )
}
```